# How can i see native code for java?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("test");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
```

This is java function. but, internal code is c/c++ code function.

so, How can i see native code function in android framework source code?

Comment: Your question is not clear, which code do you want to see what does it have to do with c/c++ ?

Comment: i want to see read() function

Comment: Download Android source code (http://source.android.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is only to inform yourself, go ahead, Android AOSP is available at this address https://android.googlesource.com
If you decide to modify something to fit your needs, you will need to rebuild Android and flash your device.

For your case, the `read()` method comes from java.io.InputStream (check your imports)
If you do a search on google `InputStream source` you should find the class, like this for example: 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/InputStream.java

Comment: Thank you for answer me!. but, How can i analysis?

I mean how follow java function to native function.

Comment: @user3697885 Check the new edit.

Comment: @user3697885 If that answer is good for you, accept it. Else, I will help you more.

Comment: @TyMarc Just a minor point: the url you posted is from OpenJDK. The Android code would be at `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/io/InputStream.java`

Comment: yeah! I have found same path. thank you!

Comment: @matiash For some reason, we can't access the link you sent. But if you follow the path all through https://android.googlesource.com/, it goes to your link and from there I can open yours. Weird.